# MySQL Workbench falsely claiming I have an error in my syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a stored procedure that determines and sets the next minute to review by getting the last reviewed timestamp and then determining what the lowest timestamp is after that.

The thing that bothers me about this is that while it works perfectly (so far), but MySQL workbench claims that I have 2 syntax errors:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`forex`@`%` PROCEDURE `set_next_minute`()
BEGIN
    SET @next_minute = (
        SELECT FLOOR(timestamp/60000) * 60
        FROM tick 
        WHERE timestamp > (
            (SELECT value 
            FROM setting 
            WHERE name = 'next_minute')
            + 60) * 1000 
        ORDER BY timestamp 
        LIMIT 1);
    UPDATE setting 
    SET value = @next_minute 
    WHERE name = 'next_minute';
END
```

1. `WHERE name = 'next_minute')` missing 'closing parenthesis'
2. `+ 60) * 1000` missing 'semicolon'

Comment: is workbench "not executing" this?

Comment: workbench is executing it, and then adds a "SYNTAX ERROR" procedure in my overview. Refreshing it brings back the normal name

Answer (score 1):

The funnier of these is that it says for the closing parenthesis it expects a closing parenthesis :-).

This is certainly a parser error and needs to be addressed. Can you file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com?

Comment: May I add: *Please file the bug report!* ;)